# Why the epipoles are the Fundamental matrix right and left null space in Computer Vision?

Tags: matrices, computer-vision

I have known that the Fundamental matrix is $\operatorname{rank}(2)$,and all the epipolar lines meet at the epipoles.

Given this identity $(e')^T\cdot (Fx)= \mathbf 0$, in order to make this equation set up for all $Fx$, we should set $e'$ value to be zero.

But, why $e'$ is called right space of the $F$, or left space? In other words, can we divide the Fundamental matrix up into $3$ by $5$ matrix ,with left-most column vector and right-most column vector $\mathbf 0$?

Comment: "Eipople" and "eipolar" are not commonly used words, as far as I can tell. Can you please provide a definition for what it is that you're talking about?

Comment: It might be a misspelling of "epipolar".

Comment: and eipoples for epipoles?

Comment: yes, sorry to spell it incorrectly. I have modifed it.

Comment: What if we see this question in a mathmetic perspective? In math ,when there is a vector and  left multiply a matrix ,let's call it  A  of which the form is a 3 by 3 square matrix or others. If the result is zero vector, the vevtor above will be called right null space of A? And the vector is the kernal of A? BTW, in mathmatics, what is the matrix kernal? I'm a elementary bird in mathmatics, hope you can explain thiese patiently.

Comment: anybody could help me ?